# Identify the correct HTTP method

Tags: web-services, restful-url

I have created a REST web-service using springboot. It has users resoruce for below urls

```
/users => get  the users in system.(GET)
/adduser => Post  a new user.(POST)
/addFriend/{friendID} => this method is to add the friendID into the current logged-in friend(the user resource has friend list) now my doubt its Its a POST request of a GET request. Currently GET method has solved my problem. But I am not sure about the correct method which is right one logically.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Restful API targets resources and does not contain actions in the URI.
Example:

> GET /users

=> get user list

> GET /users/:userid

=> get info of a user via userid

> POST /users

=> create a new user

> DELETE /users/:userid

=> delete a user via userid

> POST /users/:userid/friends

=>create a friendship and you can send body include ID of another user.(JSON/XML)

> GET /users/:userid/friends/:friendid

=> check friend between two user maybe return friendshipID or true/false

Answer (score 1):

It is a POST Request.

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol):

> The GET method requests a representation of the specified resource. Requests using GET should only retrieve data and should have no other effect.

and

> The POST method requests that the server accept the entity enclosed in the request as a new subordinate of the web resource identified by the URI. The data POSTed might be, for example, an annotation for existing resources; a message for a bulletin board, newsgroup, mailing list, or comment thread; a block of data that is the result of submitting a web form to a data-handling process; or an item to add to a database.